# Calling user defined function from AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am very new to AngularJS and I need to call a user defined function from a directive. In other words, in the example bellow I want to call the user defined function "whenSuccessFunction" when the user presses the button:

index.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var whenSuccessFunction = function(data) {
        alert(data);
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="vendor/angularjs/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myapp.js"></script>
    <my-directive x-user-defined-function="whenSuccessFunction()"></my-directive>
</body>
</html>
```

myapp.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() { 
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:true,
        template: '<button ng-click="doStuff()">Click here!</button>',
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            $scope.doStuff = function() {
                console.log('Lots of different things happen here, including some asynchronous task');
                // Now, I need to call the user defined function
                var data = 1234;
                userDefinedFunction(data);
            };
        },      
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, controllerInstance) {
            console.log(attrs.userDefinedFunction); // stings "whenSuccessFunction()"
        },
        scope: {
            // I think the answer for my issue is around the scope... but I do not know what to do next...
            userDefinedFunction: '=userDefinedFunction'
        }
    };
});
```

When I press the button it throws the following error:

```
Error: userDefinedFunction is not defined .controller/$scope.doStuff@..............
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your callback function in the directive parent scope. Otherwise Angular will not find it and wont be able to invoke it. So for example:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <my-directive x-user-defined-function="whenSuccessFunction(data)"></my-directive>
</body>
```

Then in controller:

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.whenSuccessFunction = function(data) {
        alert(data);
    };
});
```

And finally the directive also have a mistake:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<button ng-click="doStuff()">Click here!</button>',
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            $scope.doStuff = function() {
                console.log('Lots of different things happen here, including some asynchronous task');

                // this is how you pass data to the function
                $scope.userDefinedFunction({data: 1234});
            };
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, controllerInstance) {

        },

        // Use &userDefinedFunction to execute an expression
        scope: {
            userDefinedFunction: '&userDefinedFunction'
        }
    };
});
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ks40nFnhSV15QiI8vx9o?p=preview

Comment: I see what you are suggesting... But, following this approach, 'whenSuccessFunction' is within a controller peace of code. In my case, my code is going to be a third-party code, other apps (not necessarily AngularJS apps) will use my directive. Therefore, I would like to "pass" the user defined function to my directive instead of "embedding" it within my AngularJS code. Would it be possible?

Comment: @dfsq Hi,Your solution works like charm. I have a small doubt.Can we pass DOM reference as data here.I tried but it throws an exception "Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed". Is there any possible way to do?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `scope:true` (used for scope inheritance, which is not your expectation) and replace it by:

```
scope: {
    userDefinedFunction: '&xUserDefinedFunction'  //isolate scope containing a reference to function
}
```

Note the use of the `&`operator to reference function in attribute.

Comment: Removed scope:true; tried '&xUserDefinedFunction', ''&xuserDefinedFunction','&UserDefinedFunction', '&userDefinedFunction'. Unfortunately, same error message still.

Comment: By the way `x-` and `data-` prefixes are not taken into account by Angular, so it should indeed be `&userDefinedFunction`.